MongoDB aggregation query causing high CPU usage and unresponsiveness
I have a gRPC method that takes around 100 friendIds, queries MongoDB, and returns 20 records. However, during this process, the CPU usage spikes significantly, causing MongoDB to become unresponsive. My goal is to group by groupId and ensure that the number of grouped elements is 20.
Currently, there are approximately 134,000 records in the database, but we expect this number to increase.
Here is my current code:
public override async Task<GrpcActivityFeed.ActivityFeeds> Get(GrpcActivityFeed.ActivityFeedGetRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var activityFeedCollection = _dbContext.GetCollection<ActivityFeedItem>("ActivityFeedItems");
    var friendIdList = request.UserFriendIds.ToList();

    DateTime? maxDate = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.MaxDate))
    {
        maxDate = DateTime.Parse(request.MaxDate);
    }

    var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
    {
        new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("UserId", new BsonDocument("$in", new BsonArray(friendIdList)))),
        new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("CreatedOnUtc", -1)),
        new BsonDocument("$group", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", "$GroupId" },
            { "latestItem", new BsonDocument("$first", "$$ROOT") }
        }),
        new BsonDocument("$lookup", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "from", "ActivityFeedItems" },
            { "localField", "_id" },
            { "foreignField", "GroupId" },
            { "as", "groupedItems" }
        }),
        new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument("latestItem.CreatedOnUtc", -1)),
        new BsonDocument("$skip", request.Skip),
        new BsonDocument("$limit", request.Take),
        new BsonDocument("$project", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "latestItem.CreatedOnUtc", 1 },
            { "latestItem.UserId", 1 },
            { "latestItem.Type", 1 },
            { "latestItem.User", 1 },
            { "latestItem.Collection", 1 },
            { "groupedItems", 1 }
        })
    };

    var aggregation = await activityFeedCollection.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(pipeline);
    var resultList = await aggregation.ToListAsync();
    var finalResult = new List<List<ActivityFeedItem>>();

    foreach (var document in resultList)
    {
        if (!document.Contains("groupedItems"))
        {
            continue; // groupedItems field not found, skip this document
        }

        var items = document["groupedItems"].AsBsonArray;
        var activityFeedItems = items.Select(item => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ActivityFeedItem>(item.AsBsonDocument)).ToList();
        finalResult.Add(activityFeedItems);
    }

    var activityFeeds = new GrpcActivityFeed.ActivityFeeds();
    foreach (var result in finalResult.OrderByDescending(p => p.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOnUtc).FirstOrDefault().CreatedOnUtc))
    {
        var groupedItems = result.ToList();
        var latestItem = groupedItems.OrderByDescending(item => item.CreatedOnUtc).FirstOrDefault();

        var activityFeed = new ActivityFeed
        {
            Id = latestItem.Id,
            UserId = latestItem.UserId,
            Type = latestItem.Type,
            CreatedOnUtc = latestItem?.CreatedOnUtc,
            User = latestItem?.User,
            GroupedItems = groupedItems,
            TotalItemCount = groupedItems.Count,
            CollectionType = latestItem?.Collection?.Entity?.CollectionType
        };

        var grpcActivity = _mapper.Map<GrpcActivityFeed.ActivityFeed>(activityFeed);
        activityFeeds.ActivityFeeds_.Add(grpcActivity);
    }

    return activityFeeds;
}

I'm looking for the best way to optimize this query to reduce CPU usage and prevent MongoDB from becoming unresponsive. Any suggestions on how to improve this aggregation pipeline or overall approach would be greatly appreciated.
**EDIT: Here is MongoDB query log
{
  "type": "command",
  "ns": "***.ActivityFeedItems",
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "ActivityFeedItems",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "UserId": {
            "$in": [
              // userIds,
              212
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$GroupId",
          "latestItem": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "latestItem.CreatedOnUtc": -1
        }
      },
      {
        "$skip": 0
      },
      {
        "$limit": 20
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "ActivityFeedItems",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "GroupId",
          "as": "groupedItems"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "latestItem.CreatedOnUtc": 1,
          "latestItem.UserId": 1,
          "latestItem.Type": 1,
          "latestItem.User": 1,
          "latestItem.Collection": 1,
          "groupedItems": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "cursor": {
      
    },
    "$db": "***",
    "lsid": {
      "id": {
        "$binary": {
          "base64": "B3dht3N+QI2rPdH0oqcLdQ==",
          "subType": "04"
        }
      }
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
          "t": 1716875987,
          "i": 1
        }
      },
      "signature": {
        "hash": {
          "$binary": {
            "base64": "2oLIMkZ7L6RpuGikgdfKDONMkY0=",
            "subType": "00"
          }
        },
        "keyId": 7340668007347126000
      }
    }
  },
  "planSummary": "IXSCAN { UserId: 1 }",
  "keysExamined": 64152,
  "docsExamined": 64152,
  "hasSortStage": true,
  "cursorExhausted": true,
  "numYields": 64,
  "nreturned": 20,
  "queryHash": "54B9C077",
  "planCacheKey": "FD407F29",
  "queryFramework": "sbe",
  "reslen": 40127,
  "locks": {
    "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 116
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 116
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": 52
      }
    }
  },
  "readConcern": {
    "level": "local",
    "provenance": "implicitDefault"
  },
  "writeConcern": {
    "w": "majority",
    "wtimeout": 0,
    "provenance": "implicitDefault"
  },
  "storage": {
    
  },
  "remote": "***",
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "durationMillis": 426,
  "v": "6.0.15",
  "isTruncated": false
}



Your pipeline doesn't seem to be particularly complicated/heavy. If there are performance issues, it's probably due to UserId and GroupId - are these indexed in the  activityFeedCollection? Also, GroupId in ActivityFeedItems should be indexed.

Are you doing lookup with same collection "ActivityFeedItems" ? Is it correct ?
And also please make sure userid, groupid is indexed.

I have indexes for UserId and GroupId

Do you really need all these sort operations?

The data retrieved into groupedItems in the $lookup stage does not impact the $sort, $skip, or $limitstages that follow.  If you move the $lookup stage to after the $limit stage there will be less data in memory for the sort, and fewer documents to lookup, which might help performance a bit.

i tried like this but nothing changed. @Joe

That log entry shows an in-memory sort, try creating a compound index on UserId and CreatedOnUtc

I have indexes like this:
'UserId_1_CreatedOnUtc_-1', 'UserId_1_GroupId_-1_CreatedOnUtc_-1'
